# Adding subscripts or superscripts to jpgraph axis titles

Tags: php, jpgraph

The only thing I can find online is that sub/superscripts are possible in jpgraph, but I'm still trying to figure out how. I've tried carats and adding in html "sup" tags... but no luck. Any ideas?

i.e.
$graph->yaxis->title->Set('Electron density (cm^-3)');